# Data are not saved when mail is unsuccessfully sent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have this `foreach` loop which is responsible of sending a mail after saving the information to the database.

```
    foreach ($cart->items as $item){

        $order->details()->create([
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
            'discount' => $product->discount,
            'total' => $total,
        ]);

        Mail::to($product->user->email)->send(new ProductOrdered($item, $order));
    }
```

When the mail works fine, everything is perfect. Anytime the mail fails to be sent, only the first item passed to the foreach loop is saved, and an error is thrown which prevent the rest of the code from executing.

In this particular scenario, is there a way for me to prevent the the data from being saved anytime the mail fails to be sent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using database transactions?

> You may use the transaction method on the DB facade to run a set of operations within a database transaction. If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions

```
foreach ($cart->items as $item) {
    DB::transaction(function () {
        $order->details()->create([
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
            'discount' => $product->discount,
            'total' => $total,
        ]);

        Mail::to($product->user->email)->send(new ProductOrdered($item, $order));
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I'd put the transaction call *inside* the loop. Otherwise, you're going to roll back *every* bit of data even if it's the 3,029th email that fails. (Doing so will also let the rest of the emails continue sending, if you add in a try/catch too.)